# Stolen self sign server certficiate in flutter web client

Tags: flutter, ssl, self-signed

Say I have a flutter app and an intranet server. The flutter client will try to talk to the server in TLS. I understood that we can generate a self signed certificate in server and I can have flutter client app load the certificate to talk to the server. I am thinking that if I store that certificate in asset, would that be secure ?

Seems that if someone got the certificate from asset, they can then talk to the server. Is that true ? If that is true that it seems that self certified certificate is not very secure.

Answer (score 0):

Certificates are public, you're storing a copy of your self-signed certificate locally for your TLS client to trust it, as it'll only trust the system CAs by default. **So no, nothing will be compromised if you store your certificate client-side.**

What you shouldn't store client-side are *private* keys, they typically start with

`-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`.